# Google maps API (using gmapsjs), setCenter throws "undefined is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm try to set map center using [gmapjs](http://hpneo.github.io/). When I resize the window I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Here the map and the listener for the `resize` event:

```
$(function () {
    var holder = $('#map-property'),
        lat = 46.534820,
        lng = 13.024809;

    var map = new GMaps({
        div: '#'+holder.attr('id'),
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng,
        zoom: 14,
        scrollwheel: false,
        panControl : false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        draggable: true,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        zoomControlOptions:{
            style:google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        }
    })
    .addMarker({
        lat: 46.534820,
        lng: 13.024809,
        title: 'Da Matteo',
        icon: "/img/gmaps-marker.png"
    });

    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        map.setCenter(lat, lng); // here is the error!
    });
});
```

AFAIK the `setCenter` function is:

```
this.setCenter = function(lat, lng, callback) {
  this.map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));

  if (callback) {
    callback();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, `map = new Gmaps().addMarker()` returns a marker object, not a map. Therefore it has no `setCenter` method.

You can do something like:

```
var map = new Gmaps({...})
map.addMarker({...})
```

Then write the event.